# Ansible to run commands via SSH on remote hosts

Tags: ansible

I am having a problem connecting to some Checkpoint firewalls. They run a Linux, but I cannot install any Ansible.

```yaml
- name: "Connecting to Checkpoint Firewalls"
  connection: ansible.netcommon.network_cli
  gather_facts: false
  hosts: checkpoint

  tasks:
    - name: Gather facts (asa)
      ansible.netcommon.cli_command:
        command:
          - clish
          - show hostname
          - show version all
          - show asset all
          - show interfaces all
          - show lom ip-address
          - show virtual-system all
      register: checkpoint_vars

    - name: Debug
      debug:
        vars: checkpoint_vars
```

In my inventory file I have set the network OS to IOS as I assumed that the ssh session would be the same. I have also set the SSH common args to sue a bastion host to get to the target devices.

```
[checkpoint:vars]
ansible_become=no
#ansible_become_method=enable
ansible_network_os=cisco.ios.ios
ansible_connection=network_cli
ansible_user=device_user
ansible_ssh_pass='whatthefuck'
ansible_ssh_common_args='-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o PreferredAuthentications=password -o PubkeyAuthentication=no -o KexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 -o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p -q name@111.89.11.11"'
```

Now I get different error messages from the devices like

```
"msg": "unable to set terminal parameters"
```

or

```
"msg": "Error reading SSH protocol banner"
```

I assume that I should not use the `network_cli` to connect to a Linux system. But I have not found a way to use the Ansible builtin command to perform the action I need.

The problem is that I need to start a CLIsh shell first, then run multiple commands and capture the output.

UPDATE

So with help of the comments here I got it to work like this:

In the inventory file I use the SSH not Paramiko now:

```
ansible_connection=ssh
```

The Task looks like this:

```
 tasks:
    - name: Gather facts (Checkpoint GAIA)
      shell: |
         clish -c 'show hostname'
         sleep 2
         clish -c 'show version all'
         sleep 2
         clish -c 'show asset all'
      register: checkpoint_vars
```

Comment: Might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9520609/2123530

Comment: hi, I am pretty sure the SSH connection works just fine as I get the "unable to set terminal parameters" for some hosts. And it does work for my other network devices. I think the problem is that "ansible.netcommon.network_cli" is the wrong method for Linux based systems.

Comment: The error message and the given comment are related to [New LibSSH Connection Plugin for Ansible Network Replaces Paramiko](https://www.ansible.com/blog/new-libssh-connection-plugin-for-ansible-network).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According [Ansible and Check Point](https://www.ansible.com/integrations/security/checkpoint) and [Getting started with Ansible and Check Point](https://www.ansible.com/blog/getting-started-with-ansible-and-check-point) there are [modules for management (`Check_Point.Mgmt`)](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/check_point/mgmt/index.html#plugins-in-check-point-mgmt) available which seems all to connect over Web Services API.

In your case you could just try with the `raw` module according [Whats the difference between ansible `raw`, `shell` and `command`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57804071/) or with `ansible_network_os=vyos` or `nxos` according [Ansible Network Examples](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/network/user_guide/network_best_practices_2.5.html).

Comment: I am using now the "ansible_connection=ssh" and then the Ansible "shell" to execute the commands. That works very well.